# How to make messages turn non-bold when clicked on in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Unread messages appear bold, but the default setting is that they remain bold when clicked on (and it's only when another message is selected that they become non-bold).

I want messages to lose their bold font when clicked on (immediately, or after a second perhaps). I know I've altered a setting for this previously, but I can't find the setting this time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook go to the View tab, select the Reading Pane, then Options and make changes as you see fit.  In your case, select the `Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane` checkbox and select an appropriate time.

View tab ->Reading Pane -> Options

[image: Outlook 2010 reading pane options]

Answer (score 1):

1. On the *View* tab click **View Settings**
2. Click **Conditional Formatting**
3. In the *Rules for this view* list select a rule (or create a new one by clicking Add)
4. Click **Condition**
5. On the *More Choices* tab enable the **only items that are... unread** checkbox
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

View tab -> Reading Pane -> Options ->  "Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane" change waiting time to 1 second

Comment: Why what do these options do?